# Delete controls based on their Class

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I need to delete some controls in TableLayoutPanel. The code below works well for Buttons:

```
private void RemoveButtons()
{
    for (int i = TablePanel.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (TablePanel.Controls[i] is Button)
            TablePanel.Controls[i].Dispose();
    }
}
```

But, in other situations I need to delete Panel, User controls, etc. How to change the code above to delete controls based on the Class of controls in one method?

```
private void RemoveControls(Type class)
{
    for (int i = TablePanel.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (TablePanel.Controls[i] is class)
            TablePanel.Controls[i].Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "Control" which is the base class of all controls like buttons, textbox, listbox ...

Comment: With this: private void RemoveControls(Control control) ,  I get this error : The type or namespace name 'control' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This does not give an error : private void RemoveControls(Control control) { }  So another line of code must be giving the error.

Comment: @jdweng; Yes. With this: private void RemoveControls(Control control)  {... if (TablePanel.Controls[i] is control) ...} I get that error.

Comment: It would simply be : if (control is Button )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
private void RemoveControls<T>() where T : Control
{
    for (int i = TablePanel.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (TablePanel.Controls[i] is T)
            TablePanel.Controls[i].Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
RemoveControls<Button>();
```

or

```
RemoveControls<Label>();
```

However you need to keep in mind that `Dispose`-ing a control doesn't remove it from the Controls, it just makes it disposed. If you really want to remove them from the Controls object, do something like this:

```
    private void RemoveControls<T>() where T : Control
    {
        var controlsOfT = TablePanel.Controls.OfType<T>().ToList();

        controlsOfT.ForEach((c) =>
        {
            TablePanel.Controls.Remove(c);
            c.Dispose();
        });
    }
```

Which both removes them from the `Controls` collection and disposes them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IsAssignableFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Type_IsAssignableFrom_System_Type_) on each control's type.

```
private void RemoveControls(Type type)
{
    for (int i = TablePanel.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var controlType = TablePanel.Controls[i].GetType();
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(controlType))
            TablePanel.Controls[i].Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may have unintended side effects if using inherited controls.

Comment: I agree, I flipped around what `IsAssignableFrom()` should be called on and what gets passed in.